# ReactJS ValidateForm onSubmit requires a few clicks

Tags: reactjs, mern

I have a login form. I tried to validate it in React. OnSubmit on the form tag, it calls handleSubmit(). This function then calls validateField() which calls validateForm(). All to see if the formValid is true or not. When I enter the correct email and password format and click submit, it comes back false. I try it again and it comes back false.

The third time I click submit, the form is valid and submits to express. Why doesn't it recognize the state change to form valid instantly, how do I do react validation better?

Thank you a bunch

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import './resources/Home.css';
    import FormErrors from './FormErrors.js';
    import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

    class Home extends Component {

      constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
          email: '',
          password: '',
          formErrors: {email: '', password: ''},
          emailValid: false,
          passwordValid: false,
          formValid: false
        };

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.validateField = this.validateField.bind(this);
        this.validateForm = this.validateForm.bind(this);
      }

      onChange(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({[name]: value});

      }

      validateField() {
        let fieldValidationErrors = this.state.formErrors;
        let emailValid = this.state.emailValid;
        let passwordValid = this.state.passwordValid;


            emailValid = this.state.email.match(/^([\w.%+-]+)@([\w-]+\.)+([\w]{0,})$/i);
            fieldValidationErrors.email = emailValid ? '' : 'email is invalid';

            passwordValid = this.state.password.length >= 6;
            fieldValidationErrors.password = passwordValid ? '': ' password is too short';

        this.setState({formErrors: fieldValidationErrors,
                        emailValid: emailValid,
                        passwordValid: passwordValid
                      }, this.validateForm());

      }

      validateForm() {
        this.setState({formValid: this.state.emailValid && this.state.passwordValid});
      }

      handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('pressed submit');
        console.log('form valid: ' + this.state.formValid);
        this.validateField(); 

        if ( this.state.formValid === true) {
          console.log('here');

        fetch('/login', {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
          body: JSON.stringify({
            "email" : this.state.email,
            "password" : this.state.password
          })
         })
         .then(response => response.json().then(data => ({status: response.status,data:data})))
         .then(res => {  
           res.status === 200 ? alert('success') : alert('fail')
          res.data.errors.map(x => alert(x.msg)) })
         }

      }

      render() {

        return (
          <div class="page">
            <div className="Home">

              <div id="formWrap" >
             {// <div className="panel panel-default">
               // <FormErrors formErrors={this.state.formErrors} />
            //  </div>
              }
              <h2>Login</h2>
                <form id="sendInfo" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >

                  {this.state.formValid ? '' :this.state.formErrors.email}
                  <input data-lpignore="true" type="text" placeholder="email" name="em"  name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.onChange}/>

                  {this.state.formValid ?  '' : this.state.formErrors.password }
                  <input data-lpignore="true" type="text" placeholder="password" name="pw" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.onChange}/>


                  <input type="submit" id="submit"  value="submit"/>

                </form>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Home;
```

Comment: You can use npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator for better.

Comment: @HimanshuPandey can I use this in my ReactJS jsx?

Comment: yeah sure you can use 
1) npm install validator
2) import Validator from 'validator';

Comment: @HimanshuPandey Ok thanks. I'll wait for some more answers before giving the final tick. Could you reply as an answer

Comment: Done & check with your component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as below described:
 1) npm install validator & then do as below in your component or make separate component(i.e. Singup.jsx) and import in current component i.e. 
import validateSignup from './Singup';

```
import Validator from 'validator';
import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty';

export default function validateInput(data) {

  let errors = {}; 

  if (!Validator.isEmail(data.email)) {
    errors.email = 'Email is required';
  }
  if (Validator.isNull(data.password)) {
    errors.password = 'This field is required';
  }
  if (Validator.isNull(data.passwordConfirmation)) {
    errors.passwordConfirmation = 'This field is required';
  }
  return {
    errors,
    isValid: isEmpty(errors)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know this was possible.

Comment: yeah man its possible just make separate component or just call this function validateInput in your handleSubmit

Comment: The challenge is that `validateField()` is called on clicking `submit` and at that stage the new state is not available to `handleSubmit()`. Makes sense?

Comment: You may want to validate `onChange` so that by the time you `handleSubmit` the new state of input validation is available.

Comment: The solution to your problem is to figure out a way for `handleSubmit()` to listen to state changes whenever `validateField()` updates state.

Comment: It is something to do with `context` in JavaScript

Comment: Shall post an answer when I get a solution.

Comment: In the meantime, you could validate `onBlur` to avoid calling `validateField()` on every key stroke

Answer (score 0):

You can set the state 'formValid' in the 'validateField()' function only rather than using an entirely new function.

```
    validateField() {
      let fieldValidationErrors = this.state.formErrors;
      let emailValid = this.state.emailValid;
      let passwordValid = this.state.passwordValid;

      emailValid = this.state.email.match(/^([\w.%+-]+)@([\w-]+\.)+([\w]{0,})$/i);
      fieldValidationErrors.email = emailValid ? '' : 'email is invalid';

      passwordValid = this.state.password.length >= 6;
      fieldValidationErrors.password = passwordValid ? '': ' password is too short';

      this.setState({
        formErrors: fieldValidationErrors,
        emailValid: emailValid,
        passwordValid: passwordValid
      }, () => this.setState({formValid: this.state.emailValid && this.state.passwordValid}));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll be using the Validator.js as suggested by the approved answer. However, this works too thank you